# R :Read csv numeric with comma in decimal, package sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I need to read a file of type ".csv" using the library "sparklyr", in which the numeric values appear with commas. The idea is to be able to read using "spark_read_csv()" directly.

I am using:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

f<-data.frame(DNI=c("22-e","EE-4","55-W"), 
DD=c("33,2","33.2","14,55"),CC=c("2","44,4","44,9")) 

write.csv(f,"aff.csv")

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = "/home/tomas/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/", version = "2.1.0")

df <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "data", path = "/home/tomas/Documentos/Clusterapp/aff.csv", header = TRUE, delimiter = ",")

tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x =df , overwrite = T)
```

The problem, read the numbers as factor

Comment: You might want to include some sample data from the file.

Comment: Please add this data to your question, formatted as readable code.

Comment: The first column is an identifier and the others are numeric values, in which the comma identifies a number with decimal.                                                                              
                                                                                                                        
 df<-data.frame(DNI=c("22-e","EE-4","55-W"), DD=c("33,2","33.2","14,55"),CC=c("2","44,4","44,9"))             
                                                                                                
      write.csv(df,"aff.csv")

Comment: I'm looking for something like the csv2 () function of R, but of sparklyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate string inside a spark df you can use `regexp_replace` function as mentioned here:

https://spark.rstudio.com/guides/textmining/

For you problem it would work out like this:

```
tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x =df, overwrite = T)

tbl0<-tbl%>%
    mutate(DD=regexp_replace(DD,",","."),CC=regexp_replace(CC,",","."))%>%
    mutate_at(vars(c("DD","CC")),as.numeric)
```

to check your result:

```
> glimpse(tbl0)
Observations: ??
Variables: 3
$ DNI <chr> "22-e", "EE-4", "55-W"
$ DD  <dbl> 33.20, 33.20, 14.55
$ CC  <dbl> 2.0, 44.4, 44.9
```

Comment: It is understood!!,
what you do is load it from the second "df" where it uses spark_read_csv()
Excellent contribution!

Answer (score 1):

If u dont want to replace it with '.' maybe you can try this.

[spark_read_csv](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/0.9.3/topics/spark_read_csv)

Check the documentation. Use **escape** parameter to specify which character you are trying to ignore.

In this case try using:

```
df <- spark_read_csv(sc, name = "data", path = "/home/tomas/Documentos/Clusterapp/aff.csv", header = TRUE, delimiter = ",", escape = "\,").
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the "," in the numbers with "." and convert them to numeric. For instance

```
df$DD<-as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",",replacement = ".",x = df$DD))
```

Does that help?

Comment: It is a good strategy, but the objective is to be able to read the data without having to load the data in R, but to operate with Sparklyr directly. In R is the command read.csv2() that allows to read decimal numeric data with comma.